# encode/decode unicode and socket

Tags: python, sockets, unicode, recv

I wrote following two functions for converting `str` to `bytes` and `str` to `bytes`:

```
def string_to_bytes(self,string,encoding):
     value = (string.encode(encoding))
     if encoding == "utf-8":
        multiple = 2
     else:
        multiple = 1
     fmt = str(multiple * len(value)) + 's'
     return  struct.Struct(fmt).pack(value)

def bytes_to_string(self,byte_string,encoding):
   return byte_string.decode(encoding)
```

Now, When I send and recv data over soket,I get the following error:

```
11101330000040
starting connection 1 to ('127.0.0.1', 1234)
sending b'11101330000040r\xd8\xb5\xd9\x84#w\xd8\xaf\xd9\x86\xdb\x8c\xd8\xa7@001,001,0-1,0-1@ghomshei#itani\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' to connection 1
m01,2,130,12_18,وَمَن يَرْغَبُ عَن مِّلَّةِ إِبْرَٰهِۦمَ إِلَّا مَن سَفِهَ نَفْسَهُۥ وَلَقَدِ ٱصْطَفَيْنَٰهُ فِى ٱلدُّنْيَا وَإِنَّهُۥ فِى ٱلْءَاخِرَةِ لَمِنَ ٱلصَّٰلِحِينَ#m02,2,238,3_4,حَٰفِظُوا۟ عَلَى ٱلصَّلَوَٰتِ وَٱلصَّلَوٰةِ ٱلْوُسْطَىٰ وَقُومُوا۟ لِلَّهِ قَٰنِتِينَ#m03,2,277,5_7,إِنَّ ٱلَّذِينَ ءَامَنُوا۟ وَعَمِلُوا۟ ٱلصَّٰلِحَٰتِ وَأَقَامُوا۟ ٱلصَّلَوٰةَ وَءَاتَوُا۟ ٱلزَّكَوٰةَ لَهُمْ أَجْرُهُمْ عِندَ رَبِّهِمْ وَلَا خَوْفٌ عَلَيْهِمْ وَلَا هُمْ يَحْزَنُونَ#m04,3,39,5_20,فَنَادَتْهُ ٱلْمَلَٰٓئِكَةُ وَهُوَ قَآئِمٌ يُصَلِّى فِى ٱلْمِحْرَابِ أَنَّ ٱللَّهَ يُبَشِّرُكَ بِيَحْيَىٰ مُصَدِّقًۢا بِكَلِمَةٍ مِّنَ ٱللَّهِ وَسَيِّدًا وَحَصُورًا وَنَبِيًّا مِّنَ ٱلصَّٰلِحِينَ#m05,4,77,39_10,أَلَمْ تَرَ إِلَى ٱلَّذِينَ قِيلَ لَهُمْ كُفُّوٓا۟ أَيْدِيَكُمْ وَأَقِيمُوا۟ ٱلصَّلَوٰةَ وَءَاتُوا۟ ٱلزَّكَوٰةَ فَلَمَّا كُتِبَ عَلَيْهِمُ ٱلْقِتَالُ إِذَا فَرِيقٌ مِّنْهُمْ يَخْشَوْنَ ٱلنَّاسَ كَخَشْيَةِ ٱللَّهِ أَوْ أَشَدَّ خَشْيَةً وَقَالُوا۟ رَبَّنَا لِمَ كَتَبْتَ عَلَيْنَا ٱلْقِتَالَ لَوْلَآ أَخَّرْتَنَآ إِلَىٰٓ أَجَلٍ قَرِيبٍ قُلْ مَتَٰعُ ٱلدُّنْيَا قَلِيلٌ وَٱلْءَاخِرَةُ خَيْرٌ لِّمَنِ ٱتَّقَىٰ وَلَا تُظْلَم
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./multiconn-client.py", line 100, in <module>
    service_connection(key, mask)
  File "./multiconn-client.py", line 71, in service_connection
    print(payloadanalyzor_instance.bytes_to_string(recv_data,'utf-8'))
  File "/home/mohsen/codes/haq/payloadanalyzor.py", line 110, in bytes_to_string
    return byte_string.decode(encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 2047: unexpected end of data

    It raise on client, When I call  `bytes_to_string` function.
```

How can I solve the problem?

**EDIT:**
I get on client.

Comment: *string\_to\_bytes* and *bytes\_to\_string* **must be inverse**, meaning that `s == string_to_bytes(bytes_to_string(s))` and `s == bytes_to_string(string_to_bytes(s))`. Why not using "regular" encoding / decoding? Also [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you explain the idea behind that `multiple`/`Struct.pack` logic?

Comment: @AKX , size of unicode is different.

Comment: @CristiFati , Because I need to send bytes in python for `recv()` or `send()`

Comment: I know that, was wondering why *string\_to\_bytes* has more than 2 lines.

Comment: `string.encode()` already returns bytes - why do you need to use `struct` at all?

Comment: Thanks GOD, I send more data and client doesn't prevent to `EOF`. I have to limit my packet size, Or calculate my packet size for `recv()`

Comment: Do you have any recommendation for implementing dynamic size of `recv()` and `send()` ?

Comment: @PersianGulf UTF-8 is a variable length encoding – `multiple = 2` doesn't cut it at all. Besides, you're doubling the length of the encoded bytes, not the original string.

Comment: If you're using TCP sockets, you can use `sock.sendall()` to have Python deal with packetizing your data. You're still on your own as to how to know you've read enough – consider a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value scheme.